# Analysing height difference from columns and selecting max difference in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, diff

I have a .csv file containing x y data from transects ([.csv file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eN5eQkiPDzDQjZ_eb3tFcWXN-pCCh8CM)).
The file can contain a few dozen transects (example only 4).

I want to calculate the elevation change from each transect and then select the transect with the highest elevation change.

```
x         y      lines
0       3.444      1
0.009   3.445      1
0.180   3.449      1
0.027   3.449      1
...
0       2.115      2
0.008   2.115      2
0.017   2.115      2
0.027   2.116      2
```

I've tried to calculate the change with pandas.dataframe.diff but I'm unable to select the highest elevation change from this.

UPDATE: I found a way to calculate the height difference for 1 transect. The goal is now to loop this script through the different other transects and let it select the transect with the highest difference. Not sure how to create a loop from this...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter, find_peaks, find_peaks_cwt
from pandas import read_csv
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('transect4.csv', delimiter=',', header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'lines'])
df_1 = df ['lines'] == 1
df1 = df[df_1]

plt.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], label='Original Topography')

#apply a Savitzky-Golay filter
smooth = savgol_filter(df1.y.values, window_length = 351, polyorder = 5)

#find the maximums
peaks_idx_max, _ = find_peaks(smooth, prominence = 0.01)

#reciprocal, so mins will become max
smooth_rec = 1/smooth

#find the mins now
peaks_idx_mins, _ = find_peaks(smooth_rec, prominence = 0.01)

plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Height')

plt.plot(df1['x'], smooth, label='Smoothed Topography')

#plot them
plt.scatter(df1.x.values[peaks_idx_max], smooth[peaks_idx_max], s = 55,
            c = 'green', label = 'Local Max Cusp')
plt.scatter(df1.x.values[peaks_idx_mins], smooth[peaks_idx_mins], s = 55,
            c = 'black', label = 'Local Min Cusp')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#Export to csv
df['Cusp_max']=False
df['Cusp_min']=False
df.loc[df1.x[peaks_idx_max].index, 'Cusp_max']=True
df.loc[df1.x[peaks_idx_mins].index, 'Cusp_min']=True

data=df[df['Cusp_max'] | df['Cusp_min']]
data.to_csv(r'Cusp_total.csv')

#Calculate height difference
my_data=pd.read_csv('Cusp_total.csv', delimiter=',', header=0, names=['ID', 'x', 'y', 'lines'])
df_1 = df ['lines'] == 1
df1 = df[df_1]

df1_diff=pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df1_diff['Diff_Cusps']=df1_diff['y'].diff(-1)

#Only use positive numbers for average
df1_pos = df_diff[df_diff['Diff_Cusps'] > 0]
print("Average Height Difference: ", (df1_pos['Diff_Cusps'].mean()), "m")
```

Ideally, the script would select the transect with the highest elevation change from an unknown number of transects in the .csv file, which will then be exported to a new .csv file.

Comment: How do you define elevation change for each transect? Is it the change in `y` from one observation to the next one or is it the maximum of `y` minus the minimum of `y`?

Comment: Also give a sample dataframe

Comment: The dataset consists of local max and local min so it would be the elevation change between the highest max and the lowest min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `groupby` by column `lines`.

Not sure if this is what you meant when you say elevation change but this gives difference of elevations (max(y) - min(y)) for each group, where groups are formed by all rows sharing same value of 'line'each group representing one such value. This should help you with what you are missing in your logic, (sorry can't put more time in).

```
frame = pd.read_csv('transect4.csv', header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'lines'])
groups = frame.groupby('lines')
groups['y'].max() - groups['y'].min()
# Should give you max elevations of each group.
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful. Now I want to create a loop to select the highest difference from the transects in the csv file.

Comment: @SiegmundNuyts what do you mean by 'select the highest difference from transects'? Can you give an example? as it is, this code gives the max difference within all sets of rows that have same value for 'line'. Do you want to get the max of those? `(groups['y'].max() - groups['y'].min()).max() gives that. And btw if you are using plain python loops with numpy/pandas, you're throwing away all the performance gain achieved by these libraries.

Comment: The script now calculates the elevation difference for 'lines' = 1. The csv has 'lines' = 1, 2, 3, ... So I want to adjust this script that it calculates the elevation difference for all the 'lines' and then select the one with the highest elevation difference.

Comment: @SiegmundNuyts Have you even run the code in this answer? These 3 lines do the task for all 4 lines, you are doing for only one line value in your script. As I said do not use plain python loops to loop over pandas dataframes. Besides you are going to plot a graph to get the max/mix for each line value? That is way way way too bad. This post answers your original question, doesn't try at all to fix the script posted in question, which is entirely wrong approach. I am not going to help you if you intend to go in the wrong direction when you already have a better path/final solution visible.

Comment: thanks for your input. I obviously have very little knowledge of coding in Python. I worked on this script for over a week and got stuck at this stage. As you mention, it might not be the best way, which is why I asked for help here. I tried to incorporate your method but so far without results. I'll keep working on this. Thanks for your advice :-)

Comment: @SiegmundNuyts, Sorry mate, when I read my last comment, it sounds harsh. AFAIU this code should solve your problem, looks like I misunderstood it. `groupby` solves what you are stuck at, please read/play around more around it. I suggest you look up more material on pandas and numpy than plain python to get inputs about your problem. Basically these libs are tuned for efficiency for looping operations, so they're much faster (and even easier to code) to loop as compared to plain python.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I have now the max difference between the different lines. One last question: How would I print the line that gives the max value? So let's say line 1 has the max elevation, how can I print it that it returns that line?